# Combobox with searchbox at the top

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx

How to create a combobox with searchbox at the top? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox?view=winrt-19041)

Comment: Well... set the IsEditable property to true.

Answer (score 0):

> Combobox with searchbox at the top

As @Luca Lindholm  said, you could set `IsEditable` as true that could make the input auto -complete. If you want to the dropdown will display the matched item dynamically, we suggest use [`AutoSuggestBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox?view=winrt-19041). And this is related [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/auto-suggest-box).